# MySQL : Group By Clause Not Using Index when used with Case

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by, query-optimization

Im using MySQL

**I cant change the DB structure, so thats not an option sadly**

**THE ISSUE:**

- When i use GROUP BY with CASE (as need in my situation), MYSQL uses
  file_sort and the delay is humongous (approx 2-3minutes):

  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f97d8/11/0
- But when i dont use CASE just GROUP BY group_id , MYSQL easily uses
  index and result is fast:

  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f97d8/12/0

**Scenerio: DETAILED**

Table **msgs**, containing records of sent messages, with fields:

- id,
- user_id, (the guy who sent the message)
- type, (0=> means it's group msg. All the msgs sent under this are marked by group_id. So lets say group_id = 5 sent 5 msgs, the table will have 5 records with group_id =5 and type=0. For type>0, the group_id will be NULL, coz all other types have no group_id as they are individual msgs sent to single recipient)
- group_id (if type=0, will contain group_id, else NULL)

**Table contains approx 10 million records for user id 50001 and with different types (i.e group as well as individual msgs)**

Now the QUERY:

```
SELECT 
  msgs.*
FROM
  msgs 
  INNER JOIN accounts 
    ON (
      msgs.user_id = accounts.id
    ) 
WHERE 1 
  AND msgs.user_id IN (50111) 
  AND msgs.type IN (0, 1, 5, 7) 
GROUP BY CASE `msgs`.`type` WHEN 0 THEN `msgs`.`group_id` ELSE `msgs`.`id` END 
ORDER BY `msgs`.`group_id` DESC
LIMIT 100
```

I **HAVE** to get summary in a single QUERY,

so msgs sent to group lets say 5 (have 5 records in this table) will be shown as 1 record for summary (i may show COUNT later, but thats not an issue).

The individual msgs have NULL as group_id, so i cant just put 'GROUP BY group_id ' coz that will Group all individual msgs to single record which is not acceptable.

Sample output can be something like:

```
id    owner_id,    type    group_id    COUNT   
1       50001       0       2           5    
1       50001       1       NULL        1    
1       50001       4       NULL        1    
1       50001       0       7           5
1       50001       5       NULL        1
1       50001       5       NULL        1
1       50001       5       NULL        1
1       50001       0       10          5
```

Now the problem is that the GROUP condition after using CASE (which i currently think that i have to because i only need to group by group_id if type=0) is causing alot of delay coz it's not using indexes which it does if i dont use CASE (like just group by group_id ). Please view SQLFiddles above to see the explain results

Can anyone plz give an advice how to get it optimized

**UPDATE**

I tried a workaround , that does somehow works out (drops INITIAL queries to 1sec). Using union, what it does is, to minimize the resultset by union that forces SQL to write on disk for filesort (due to huge resultset), limit the resultset of group msgs, and individual msgs (view query below)

-- first part of union retrieves group msgs (that have type 0 and needs to be grouped by group_id). Applies the limit to captivate the out of control result set

-- The second query retrieves individual msgs, (those with type !=0, grouped by msgs.id - not necessary but just to be save from duplicate entries due to joins). Applies the limit to captivate the out of control result set

-- JOins the two to retrieve the desired resultset

Here's the query:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  (
    (
      SELECT 
      msgs.id as reference_id, user_id, type, group_id
    FROM
      msgs 
      INNER JOIN accounts 
        ON (msgs.user_id = accounts.id) 
     WHERE 1 
       AND accounts.id IN (50111 ) AND type = 0
      GROUP BY msgs.group_id 
      ORDER BY msgs.id  DESC
      LIMIT 40
     ) 
    UNION
    ALL 
    (
      SELECT 
      msgs.id as reference_id, user_id, type, group_id
      FROM
      msgs 
      INNER JOIN accounts 
        ON (
          msgs.user_id = accounts.id
        ) 
    WHERE 1 
      AND msgs.type != 0
      AND accounts.id IN (50111) 
    GROUP BY msgs.id 
    ORDER BY msgs.id 
    LIMIT 40
    )
  ) AS temp 
ORDER BY reference_id 
LIMIT 20,20
```

But has alot of caveats,

-I need to handle the limit in inner queries as well. Lets say 20recs per page, and im on page 4. For inner queries , i need to apply limit 0,80, since im  not sure which of the two parts had how many records in the previous 3 pages. So, as the records per page and number of pages grow, my query grows heavier. Lets say 1k rec per page, and im on page 100 , or 1K, the load gets heavier and time exponentially increases

- I need to handle ordering in inner queries and then apply on the resultset prepared by union , conditions need to be applied on both inner queries seperately(but not much of an issue)

-Cant use calc_found_rows, so will need to get count using queries seperately

The main issue is the first one. The higher i go with the pagination , the heavier it gets

Comment: In the absence of any sample input, I find sample output deeply distressing.

Comment: There is no user_id in this table. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. You do not need to provide 5m INSERTS. Twelve is ususally more than enough to be representative. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry sorry for the delay, its done:

Comment: It's still a mess.

Comment: There's no `user_id` in `msgs`.  Please fix the Question.

Comment: @RickJames , just updated the question. It's basically user_id. There's no need for owner_id. Sorry about that. I've got a workaround using unions and stuff, but it's not perfect. So, i'll be eager to see if there's a way  to have GROUP BY CASE optimized.

Comment: No columns from `accounts` are used; why `JOIN` to it?

Comment: The values of `msgs.*` are unpredictable since you are neither `GROUPing BY` them nor are they aggregates.  Perhaps you meant `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: The Fiddles don't return any results.

Comment: @RickJames they would now. Just updated it.

Comment: The two queries are inconsistent -- one orders by `msgs.id`, the other by `msgs.group_id`.  Please remove or change the incorrect query.

Comment: I still need the answer to "No columns from accounts are used; why JOIN to it?"

Comment: hi, just updated the ordering column. Needs to msgs.id , tx for pointing that out. This is actually just prototype of the system that im currently working on. I have to use accounts info there. Joining to accounts table and data used is abit classified , so im not posting it here. Lets just say that its mandatory. Update: Even if i remove accounts join, the file sort still makes alot of delay

Comment: Please, Mr. Khan, read this. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056  Also, you are using the `GROUP BY` facility in a nonstandard way, making it hard to understand your intent. Please read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html  Also, you will always have filesort if you order an aggregate. Seeing it in `EXPLAIN` output may be confusing you. https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Would this run faster?

```
SELECT  id, user_id, type, group_id
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  id, user_id, type, group_id, IFNULL(group_id, id) AS foo
            FROM  msgs
            WHERE  user_id IN (50111)
              AND  type IN (0, 1, 5, 7) 
      )
    GROUP BY  foo
    ORDER BY  `group_id` DESC
    LIMIT  100
```

It needs `INDEX(user_id, type)`.

Does this give the 'correct' answer?

```
SELECT  DISTINCT *
    FROM  msgs
    WHERE  user_id IN (50111)
      AND  type IN (0, 1, 5, 7)
    GROUP BY  IFNULL(group_id, id)
    ORDER BY  `group_id` DESC
    LIMIT  100
```

(It needs the same index)

Comment: Didnt have any significant impact though.sadly. At current load, the initial query that I had posted takes ~37s, your first query takes 31s (its better, but i need to get it down to max5 as per req -- `profiler` says `Copying to tmp` took 29.3s out of 31, makes sense), and your second query took ~47 s (acc to profiler, 25s fr sending data, 19.5 for copying to temp). I did create user_id_type index, and it did select it as a key but didnt use index acc. to Extra info in Explain

Comment: also, w.r.t your first query, derived table with millions of possible results when finally grouped and ordered, can we do something about this huge disk i/o and file sort? Every scenario is leading me to file sort, which is the main issue here

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` after adding my index.  And provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: Here's the link to explain.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/befc4/5/0. you may view show create at the left pane

Comment: Rick, i've update the original post with an alternate solution, which isnt good enough. Take a moment to read the UPDATE section in first post to review the workaround and the caveats it possess